# How to the modify the array of objects and return the latest updated field?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, postgresql, express

I have an object  which I am getting from the DB, You can see the object which is coming from the DB
This is what i'am getting from the DB.

```
[{
      id:1,
      cust_fname: "rock",
      cust_no:"C001",
      cust_need: "urgent",
      cust_place: "poland",
      date_created: "2021-04-16 18:50:40.658+00",
   },
   {
    id:1,
    cust_fname: "rock",
    cust_no:"C001",
    cust_need: "not-urgent",
    cust_place: "poland",
    date_created: "2021-04-16 19:50:40.658+00"
   },
   {
    id:2,
    cust_fname: "rmbo",
    cust_no:"C002",
    cust_need: "not-urgent",
    cust_place: "England",
    date_created: "2021-04-16 18:50:40.658+00"
   },
   {
    id:3,
    cust_fname: "ram",
    cust_no:"C004",
    cust_need: "urgent",
    cust_place: "USA",
    date_created: "2021-04-16 18:50:40.658+00"
   },
    {
    id:3,
    cust_fname: "ram",
    cust_no:"C004",
    cust_need: "not-urgent",
    cust_place: "USA",
    date_created: "2021-04-16 20:50:40.658+00"
   }
  ]
```

I want to modify the above object such that the it should only return latest inserted vlaue if the array of object has two same object with the same id along with all the other object.

just posting the object output which I want for more clarity.

removing the object with id:1 which has date_created: "2021-04-16 18:50:40.658+00";

```
[{
   id:1,
   cust_fname: "rock",
   cust_no:"C001",
   cust_need: "not-urgent",
   cust_place: "poland",
   date_created: "2021-04-16 19:50:40.658+00"
  },
  {
   id:2,
   cust_fname: "rmbo",
   cust_no:"C002",
   cust_need: "not-urgent",
   cust_place: "England",
   date_created: "2021-04-16 18:50:40.658+00"
  },
  {
   id:3,
   cust_fname: "ram",
   cust_no:"C004",
   cust_need: "urgent",
   cust_place: "USA",
   date_created: "2021-04-16 20:50:40.658+00"
  }
 ]
```

Looking for solution how i can modify this obj or any other way also be aprriciated.

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sort and a filter

You could alternatively use a Set.

```js
const data = [{ id:1, cust_fname: "rock", cust_no:"C001", cust_need: "urgent", cust_place: "poland", date_created: "2021-04-16 18:50:40.658+00", }, { id:1, cust_fname: "rock", cust_no:"C001", cust_need: "not-urgent", cust_place: "poland", date_created: "2021-04-16 19:50:40.658+00" }, { id:2, cust_fname: "rmbo", cust_no:"C002", cust_need: "not-urgent", cust_place: "England", date_created: "2021-04-16 18:50:40.658+00" }, { id:3, cust_fname: "ram", cust_no:"C004", cust_need: "urgent", cust_place: "USA", date_created: "2021-04-16 18:50:40.658+00" }, { id:3, cust_fname: "ram", cust_no:"C004", cust_need: "not-urgent", cust_place: "USA", date_created: "2021-04-16 20:50:40.658+00" } ];
  
  let newData = data.slice(0); // copy the data
  newData = newData.sort((a,b) =>  {  
    if (a.id===b.id) { // if same ID sort date in descending order
      if (b.date_created > a.date_created) return 1; 
      if (a.date_created > b.date_created) return -1
    }  
    else return (a.id < b.id) ? -1 : 1; // else sort in ascending order
  }).filter(({id},i) => { // filter on unique IDs
    if (i>0) return id!==newData[i-1].id
    return true;
  }) 
  console.log(newData)
```

Comment: Thanks, but When i have tried the same logic with the modified object not returning he same result. i have updated the obj and desired result.

Comment: Thanks, Can you please add explanation if possible?